# Join another table with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

I want to join another table if a column in current table equals to a specific value. ( ENUM type )

for example, assume a `status` column which has 4 types of ( Public, OnlyMe, Friend, Group )

I want to join table `groups` only when `status` = Group

Something like this.

This is not mysql syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ( status = Public OR status = OnlyMe OR status = Friend )
OR ( IF(status=Group) JOIN groups )
```

How can I do that in mysql?

Comment: What do you want to happen if `status` is something else - do you want no rows in the result for those, or `NULL` values in the joined columns for those rows?

Comment: I think what you need is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Something like `SELECT * FROM posts LEFT JOIN groups ON status = group and /*your join condition*/`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (I made up several column names for your tables):

```
SELECT p.id, p.status, p.text, g.name
FROM posts p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN groups g
        ON (p.status = 'Group' AND p.groupId = g.id);
```

Comment: So you don't think 'group' is a string? ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry I have no idea, I don't have the OP's schema. Presumably he can figure that part out himself.